# Is there any way to add url parameters to the backbone destroy method

Tags: backbone.js

Right now I am passing data via headers in the destroy request like shown below

```
            this.model.destroy(
            {
               headers: {
                  'myId': myId
               }
            }
        );
```

Is it possible to pass myId as the url parameter to delete request ?

Thanks,
Prats

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `data` in object in the `destroy` params

```
this.model.destroy(
            {
               data: {
                  'myId': myId
               }
            }
```